# Error Read File CSV in list Folder

Tags: c#, file, syntax-error, system.io.file

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\", "*.csv");
foreach (var file in filePaths)
{
    //  string[] datacsv = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("D:\\LP02_1506172300.csv");
    string[] datacsv2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(file);
    string[] data_col = null;
    int x = 0;
    foreach (string textcsv in datacsv2)
    {
        data_col = textcsv.Split(',');

        if (x == 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count()-1; i++)
            {
                Table.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);

            }
            x++;
        }
        else
        {
                Table.Rows.Add(data_col);
        }
    }
    Gridviews.DataSource = Table;
    this.Controls.Add(Gridviews);
```

Error

> "Table.Columns.Add(data_col[i])" that A column named 'Date' already
>   belongs to this DataTable.

thank in advance

Comment: Will be useful if you show how the file looks like

Comment: Does 'Date' appear more than once in this file you have?

Comment: The first line in your csv file has multiple columns with the name `Date`.

Comment: In file header column repeat name
how to not header column name next csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Error says it all, Date column already exists so you'll need to assign the column a different name.

Comment: In file header column repeat name 
how to not header column name next csv file?

Comment: Sorry I'm nit sure what you mean but there is no way in a DataTable to repeat the same column name sorry.

Comment: Example:
CSV File1 
Date               Time         Name  Nickname
19/04/2013    13:00:00   John    Jack
.
.
CSV File2 
Date               Time         Name  Nickname
20/05/2013    15:00:00    Jame    Jane
.
.
CSV..

Comment: Are you adding multiple CSV files to the same data table? If so, ignore the first line on all subsequent CSV files.